# How can I backup an Hyper-V VM in Windows 8?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-8

How can I easily backup Hyper-V VM in windows 8?  I windows 2012 I would do:

wbadmin start backup –backupTarget: –hyperv:

But in Windows 8, the option -hyperv doesn't seem to exist.

Thanks!

Comment: and you do mean while its running correct?

Comment: yes, just like we can do in 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You migh be interested by a powerful powershell script : http://www.myotherpcisacloud.com/post/2013/06/23/Psst-You-Want-A-Script-To-Backup-Your-Lab-VMs.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.